# Onchange 1st date picker, 2nd datepicker will change

Tags: jquery, datepicker

in my form, i have 2 datepicker (eg : date1, date2). Date1 is approval deadline and date2 is confirmation daedline. Approval deadline should be equal or more than confirmation deadline. I'm using this datepicker sample.

```
$myCalendar = new tc_calendar("date1", true);
$myCalendar->setIcon("calendar/images/iconCalendar.gif");
$myCalendar->setDate(date('d'), date('m'), date('Y'));
$myCalendar->setPath("calendar/");
$myCalendar->zindex = 150; //default 1
$myCalendar->setYearInterval(date('Y'), date('Y')+2);
$myCalendar->dateAllow('2011-01-01','');
$myCalendar->setSpecificDate($MalHolidays, 0, '');
$myCalendar->setSpecificJapanDate($JapHolidays, 0, '');
$myCalendar->setAlignment('right', 'bottom'); //optional          
$myCalendar->writeScript();
```

So. I want if user change date2, date1 will automatically change accordingly (same as input for date2).
But whenever date1 is change, it will effect itself only (only date1 change). Hopefully you can understand this situation.

I think that this can be done using jquery, but i'am new in jquery, i hope that you guys can help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `change` event and then use the [option](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-option) to set the [minDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate) of the approval deadline.

```
$("#date2").change(function(){
    var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
    $('#date1').datepicker('option', 'minDate', date)
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6sQTF/)

Comment: how can i check if it really function?can i put alert(date); under the 2nd line?between i try your demo, but not functioning.

Comment: @user2699175 you can select a date in the second field and then open first one, you can see that the date < second date is disabled

Comment: oh ok, so that's what minDate do is it?disabled date less than date given. but it's not working with my datepicker, are all datepicker can used this function?how can i check that?